# Populate Table With Help of PopOverController - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using a `UIButton`, on clicking it I want to display the contents that are present in my `NSMutableArray` in `UITableView` with the help of `UIPopOverController` i.e. I want a `UITableView` to pop up whose cells show the contents of my `NSMutableArray`.

I am using the following lines of code:

```
UITableViewController *table= [[UITableViewController alloc]init];

table.delegate = self;

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:table];
self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;


NSString *hDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *hFilePath = [hisDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hhhh.txt"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:hFilePath ];
NSMutableArray *kkkk = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    [kkkk addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];    
}

table = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
// Set up the image view and add it to the view but make it hidden
[window addSubview:table];
table.hidden = YES;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I am unable to get the `UITableView` to pop up on the press of my `UIButton`. Can anyone help me to sort it out?

Comment: You want to display tableview or popover?

Comment: I think it would be popover !! I am pretty new to Objective C .. dont really know ..

Comment: whats is your proper requirement do u want to show the table inside a popover?

Comment: yeah .. I want to populate a table inside a popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show the `UITableView` in the `UIPopOverController` is by creating a new `UIViewController` class. And invoking it in `initWithContentViewController` method of `UIPopOverController`.

**1.** Create a new `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` class. Create an instance of it.

**2.** Use the instance in the `initWithContentViewController` method of `UIPopOverController`.

**3.** Mention from where it should "pop"

For Example in your `Button` action :

```
-(IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender

{
   YourNewViewController*newVC=[[YourNewViewController alloc]init];

   UIPopoverController*somePopOver=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:catergoryVC]; //Tell which view controller should be shown
   [somePopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)]; // set content size of popover
   [somePopOver presentPopoverFromRect:yourButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; //From where it should "pop"

}
```

It seems you want to present it from a `UIBarButtonItem` so  instead of `presentPopoverFromRect` use `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem`

```
 [somePopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am getting some error in your last line of "[somePopOver presentPopoverFromRect:yourButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; //From where it should "pop"
" that property 'frame' not found on object of type UIBarButtonItem. How should I get over it ??

Comment: @kamalbhai it seems you want to pop from a `UIBarButtonItem`, so for that purpose you must use `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourBarButtonItem`. I'll do an edit.

Comment: I think the direction of popOver should be Any .. if it is Up .. My app just stops. Otherwise it works fine .. thanks a lot. But the popover is empty .. How should I populate it with the contents of my array ??

Comment: Oh sorry didnt check in direction part. For that you should implement the `datasource` of `UITableView` in the new `UIViewController` class that you created, that is you should have your array in `YourNewViewController` and use `datasource` and populate the table. I hope you know how to populate a `UITableView`

Comment: I know how to populate a TableView but I'm getting confused here. I have used UITableViewController and not UITableView.

Comment: It'll be the same, you just have to populate your array in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display popover on press of button click, then first add your button in viewcontroller, display that view controller as follows:
In app delegate write code:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubView:viewController.view];
```

In MyViewController add button and provide target to that button displayPopup as follows:

```
-(void)displayPopup:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewController *tblViewPopover = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    tblViewPopover.tableView.delegate = self;
    tblViewPopover.tableView.dataSource = self;
    tblViewPopover.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tblViewPopover.tableView.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    float theWidth = 280;
    tblViewPopover.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(theWidth,200);

    if(m_popOvrController){
        [m_popOvrController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        [m_popOvrController release];
        m_popOvrController=nil;
    }    
    m_popOvrController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tblViewPopover];
    [tblViewPopover release];

        [m_popOvrController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];

}
```

and you can use tableview delegate methods to display data in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

I think, UIPopoverViewController is initialized using UIViewController and here you are using UIView(UITableView).

Can you please try using UITableViewController instead?

Also, if things does not work according to plan when you create it using the code try using an XIB explicitely.

This should help.